# How to use ~/.bash_profile environment variables when using "Run Script" in "Build Phases" for XCode 6.1?

Tags: c++, xcode6, build-process, osx-yosemite, pre-build-event

I have a cross platform unit testing framework that I use for C++. In order to build and run the tests in XCode 6.1 I need to run a python script as part of a prebuild script.

Since I use the same unit testing framework for multiple projects I figured it'd be great to use environment variables in my `~/.bash_profile` to point to the resources necessary for the python script. But it seems that XCode 6.1 doesn't load the `bash_profile` before running the script in the build process. Are there alternatives to using the `bash_profile`? Maybe I could add my environment variables to the XCode environment variables list? But this seems to be changing with each update to OSX. I can't seem to figure out where I can add environment variables for XCode 6.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run a shell script by adding a build phase to your target. The instructions are also [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html).

1. Select the project file
2. Select "Build Phases" at the top
3. Select Editor > Add Build Phase > Add Run Script Build Phase
4. Add your script in the box provided

in your case you can do:

source ~/.bash_profile

python [your_script]

You can rearrange the order of your build phases by dragging them into the order you want.

NOTE: The environment variables defined in ~/.bash_profile will not be there when you run your program (at least in my experience).  To add environment variables to the run command:

1. Select Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...
2. Select Run on the side bar
3. Select the Arguments tab
4. Put any Environment variables needed by your program in the proper section

Comment: How to you access that value, having trouble with the syntax